# Doctrine (postgresql) Pessimistic Locking - doesn't throw PessimisticLockException

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine-orm, locking, pessimistic

I try to use Pessimistic Locking with Doctrine ORM for PostgreSql.
Doctrine and PostgreSql with default configurations (without any changes).

This is code example (Symfony Command).

`$sleep` - this is time in seconds

```
$manager = $this->getContainer()->get('mmi.manager.message');
$conn = $manager->em()->getConnection();

$manager->em()->getConnection()->beginTransaction();
try {
    $entity = $manager->repo()->find('cd7eb9e9', LockMode::PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);

    $entity->setState(EntityActionInterface::STATE_IN_PROGRESS);
    $manager->em()->persist($entity);
    $manager->em()->flush();

    $ts = (new \DateTime())->getTimestamp();
    $output->writeln("TS: {$ts}");

    if ($sleep) {
        $output->writeln("Sleep: {$sleep}");
        sleep($sleep);
    }

    $entity->setMessage([$ts]);
    $manager->em()->persist($entity);
    $manager->em()->flush();

    $conn->commit();
} catch (PessimisticLockException $ex) {
    var_dump(get_class($ex));

    $conn->rollBack();
    throw $ex;
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
    var_dump(get_class($ex));

    $conn->rollBack();
    throw $ex;
}
```

**How tested**

Run two command. First command runs with timeout 20 seconds. Second command runs without any timeout.

**Expected result**

Second command throws `PessimisticLockException`

**Actual result**

Second command waits for first **transaction commit** and then updates row.

**Question**

What should I do to make Doctrine throw `PessimisticLockException` if row is now locked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fo first:** How working `PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` for PostgreSql platform

PESSIMISTIC_WRITE - this is query `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`. This query lock selected row and other conections, which requested the same row, waitng for current connection finish it's work.

In my case i start two processes and second one waiting for finish first one. And this is correct behavior.

**My mistake:** i'm explore Doctrine source code and find `PessimisticLockException` class. So, i decide that Doctrine throw this exception when used pessimistic lock. But this class don't used anywhere in Doctrine.

**So, how i resolved this issue.**

My current implementation required nowait behavior for locked rows. And PostgreSql 9.5 has this feature - [SKIP LOCKED](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What's_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.5#SKIP_LOCKED). But Doctrine doesn't have implementation for this feature.

**What we can do?**

We can override doctrine postgresql platfrom class.

```
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\PostgreSqlPlatform;

class PgSqlPlatform extends PostgreSqlPlatform
{
    /**
     * Returns the FOR UPDATE expression.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getForUpdateSQL()
    {
        return 'FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED';
    }
}
```

Define it's as service

```
#app/config/services.yml
services:
    mmi.dbal.pgsql_platform:
        class: {Namespace}\PgSqlPlatform
```

And set tot doctrine config

```
#app/config/config.yml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        connections:
            mmi:
                driver:   pdo_pgsql
                host:     ...
                ...
                platform_service: 'mmi.dbal.pgsql_platform'
```

That's all. Now we can use Pessimistic lock without waiting.